# stagger doesn't exist in Popmotion's package

Tags: react-native, popmotion

im getting the following error, when trying to use Popmotion's packages in my react-native expo app. `ERROR  TypeError: (0, _popmotion.stagger) is not a function. (In '(0, _popmotion.stagger)(array-content, 4000 / 5)', '(0, _popmotion.stagger)' is undefined).`  I've imported stagger like this `import {stagger} from 'popmotion'` however, when i inspect the Popmotion package's folder, i can't found where stagger is located or is declared and vscode can't even give me a suggestion about it because it doesn't exist. if someone knows where i should import it from or if that name has been changed

Answer (score 0):

Well fixed, this was problem of package version, so in case you are having the same issue, try to check up the version of Popmotion you are using